# What does class members means? In -keepclassmembers Proguard

Tags: java, android, libgdx, annotations, proguard

Hi I'm trying to use Proguard in my Libgdx Project, but i dont understand whats does class members means, when I use **-keepclassmembers**, because I also have **-keep**, for keep classes. I don't know if this is a java topic or proguard. Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class members are class fields and methods.

```
-keep public class * extends BaseClass
```

will keep classes and class members that extends BaseClass from being removed or renamed.

```
-keepclassmembers public class * extends BaseClass
```

will keep class members only of classes that extends BaseClass from being removed or renamed.

Comment: But I don't understand what does class members means :(

Comment: Class members are class fields and class methods.

Comment: Thanks man, you save my day, I think this problem was because my horrible english, thank you

Answer (score 0):

-keepclassmembers [,modifier,...] class_specification
Specifies class members to be preserved, if their classes are preserved as well. For example, you may want to keep all serialization fields and methods of classes that implement the Serializable interface.

It means that you don't want optimization in those classes (remember that proguard when set to minimizeEnabled to true, will not compile all the unused methods, classes and variables) and with this tags, they will all be preserved.

Reference:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepclassmembers